# Getting StackOverflow Error

Tags: java, stack, stack-overflow, depth-first-search, sudoku

I'm trying to write a program that takes a Sudoku puzzle and solves it.
However, I'm running into a StackOverflow error at this line:

```
Move nMove = new Move(current.nextMove(current, sboard).i, current.nextMove(current, sboard).j);
```

It has a method isLegal that checks for whether the move is valid. If move is valid and the next move is also valid, it adds it to a stack. If it is valid but the next move is not, it should keep searching for a valid number. 
Not sure what's causing it.

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class Board {
    Stack<Move> stack = new Stack<Move>(); 
    int boardSize = 9;
    public int[][] sboard = {{2,0,0,3,9,5,7,1,6},
            {5,7,1,0,2,8,3,0,9},
            {9,3,0,7,0,1,0,8,2},
            {6,8,2,0,3,9,1,0,4},
            {3,5,9,1,7,4,6,2,8},
            {7,1,0,8,6,0,9,0,3},
            {8,6,0,4,1,7,2,9,5},
            {1,9,5,2,8,6,4,3,7},
            {4,2,0,0,0,0,8,6,1}};

    public Board() {
        //for every cell in board:
        for (int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < boardSize; j++) {
                //get the value of each cell
                int temp = getCell(i,j);
                //if cell is empty:
                if (temp == 0) {
                    //print out location of cell
                    System.out.print ("("+i+", "+j+") ");

                    //guess values for that cell
                    solve(i, j);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //places a value into specified cell
    public void setCell(int value, int row, int col) {
        sboard[row][col] = value;
    }

    //returns value contained at specified cell
    public int getCell(int row, int col) {
        return sboard[row][col];
    }

    //if value is legal, continue
    public boolean isLegal(int value, int row, int col) {
        int r = (row / boardSize) * boardSize;
        int c = (col / boardSize) * boardSize;

        for (int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < boardSize; j++) {
                if (value == getCell(i, col) || value == getCell(row, j)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    //guesses values for empty cells
    public boolean solve(int i, int j) {
        //set location as current
        Move current = new Move(i, j);
        Move nMove = new Move(current.nextMove(current, sboard).i, current.nextMove(current, sboard).j);
        //guesses values 1 through 9 that are legal
        for (int k = 1; k <= 9; k++) {
            //if a legal value is found and the next move is possible:
            if(isLegal(k, i, j) && solve(nMove.i, nMove.j)) {
                //add current to stack
                stack.push(current);
                //enter the value k into the cell
                setCell(k, i, j);
                //print new value
                System.out.print(sboard[i][j]+"\n");
                //return as true
                return true;
            }

            else if (stack.empty()){

            }
            //if next move is not possible
            else if(!solve(nMove.i, nMove.j)){
                //remove last "solved" location from stack
                stack.pop();
                //solve last location again
                solve(stack.peek());
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void solve(Move m) {
        solve(m.i, m.j);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Board b = new Board();
    }  
};

class Move {
    int i, j; 

    public Move(int i, int j) {
        this.i = i; 
        this.j = j;
    }

    public int i() { return i;}

    public int j() { return j;}

    public Move nextMove(Move current, int[][] sboard){
        for (int i = current.i; i < 9; i++) {
            for (int j = current.j; j < 9; j++) {
                //get the value of each cell
                int temp = sboard[i][j];
                if (temp == 0) {
                    return new Move(i, j);
                }
            }   
        }
        return current;
    }
};
```

Comment: stackoverflow errors are usually caused by recursive functions that don't terminate. your solve() function seems to be recursive...think about the base condition, and when it should terminate/stop calling itself.

Comment: You definitely want to move that `solve` function call out of your constructor.

Comment: Yeah it's probably due to a recursive loop; you can verify by catching the exception and calling ex.printStackTrace() to have a look at the method hierarchy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, it seems redundant to me to have this function in the form `current.nextMove(current, board)`.  You can either make this function static, or remove the `Move current` parameter.

But taking a look at your `solve(i, j)` function, you essentially have this:

1. Assume `sboard[i][j] = 0` (which it clearly does, in some cases, from your input).
2. Assume you call `solve(i, j)`.
3. `current` will be `new Move(i, j)`.
4. `nMove` will then also be `new Move(i, j)` (since in Move#nextMove,
   you essentially say `if sboard[i][j] == 0`, which it does from step
   1).
5. You will end up calling `solve(nMove.i, nMove.j)`
6. Since `nMove.i == i` and `nMove.j == j`, you are essentially calling `solve(i, j)` over again.

Since you're calling the same function with the same parameter, and you're not reaching any base case, you will end up with a stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

As you have defined an (explicit) stack, you should not call solve() recursively.

Just loop, pop a board, generate all valid next moves, see if one of them is a solution, and if not, push them on the stack.

(I couldn't find where you verify that the board is complete, but I am probably tired.)

Btw, the stack should probably be a Dequeue. I believe a stack is synchronized which slows down the code.